# Concatenate file weight less than the sum of the files

Tags: filesize, cat, ls

I have done these commands to concatenate the files into one file:

```
$ ls -1 | wc -l
16916
$ ls -1 *.txt | wc -l
16916
$ ls -lh | head -1
total 93M
$ cat *.txt > ../nectar_3.txt
$ ls -lh ../nectar_3.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 llopis llopis 52M May 25 16:03 ../nectar_3.txt
```

Why is the resulting file size half of the sum of the size of all files? The only explanation I can found is about rounding in the `ls -lh` command, but I couldn't find anything (using `ls -lk` outputs almost the same 92.76953125M)

Comment: You've go almost 17000 files, and the size total at the top is rounded. 16,000+ rounding errors can add to a very huge difference.

Comment: So there is rounding in ls -h or -k and the total amount is summed from the individual rounded size of each file?

Comment: try it out. stuff a few smallish files into a dir, then just do `ls -lk` and manually sum up the sizes. on my test dir, the total header shows 137k, while a manual addition comes to 101k

Comment: This should go to an answer then, thanks for clarifying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `total` is rounded, and is not guaranteed to be accurate:

Simple example:

```
marc@panic$ ls -lk
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 marc marc 6000 May 25 08:39 test1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 marc marc 7000 May 25 08:39 test2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 marc marc 8000 May 25 08:39 test3.txt
```

Three simple files, total size = 21,000 bytes, yet the `total` shows `24`.